# Data given in django model form is not getting displayed in another page

Tags: django

```
#my Models.py file
from django.db import models
# Create your models here.

class EmpModel(models.Model):
    empName = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    empJob = models.CharField(max_length = 20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.empID

# myForms.py file
from django.forms import ModelForm
from myWebApp.models import EmpModel

class EmpModelForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = EmpModel
        fields = [ "empName", "empJob"]

#myViews.py File
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.db import models
from myWebApp.models import EmpModel
from django.template import loader
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.forms import modelformset_factory
# Create your views here.
from .forms import EmpModelForm

def empDetails(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = EmpModelForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            empFormSave = form.save()
            empInfoData = EmpModel.objects.all()
            return render(request, "empInfoData.html", {"empInfoData" : empInfoData})
    else:
        form_class = EmpModelForm
        return render(request, "empInfo.html", {"form" : form_class})
        
#myCollectedDateDisplay Page
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
<head>
    <meta charset = "UTF-8">
    <title>Employee Information Submitted</title>
</head>
    <body>
    <h2>Employee Data available in the system</h2>
            <p>Employee Name : {{ empInfoData.empName }}</p>
            <<p>Employee Job : {{ empInfoData.empJob }}</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

1. Initially I had many modelfields like positiveinteger, datetime, etc.. I was getting integrity error. So, I removed and kept only charfield. The integrity error is resolved and page is being displayed but data is showing empty
2. I have done "python manage.py makemigrations"
3. python manage.py migrate

Comment: `empInfoData` is a *collection* of `EmpModel` items, not a sigle one, hence `.empName`...

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems. The first is that if `empDetails` is called with a post, and the form is invalid, nothing is returned, which will raise an error.

Secondly, in your template `empInfoData` is a collection. You could change the template to:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
<head>
    <meta charset = "UTF-8">
    <title>Employee Information Submitted</title>
</head>
    <body>
    <h2>Employee Data available in the system</h2>
            {% for empData in empInfoData %}
            <p>Employee Name : {{ empData.empName }}</p>
            <p>Employee Job : {{ empData.empJob }}</p>
            {% endfor %}
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This really worked.  Thanks a lot. But, I am able to see all the previous data submitted from the form. Can u help me to clean the previously posted data?

Comment: You can use the old template if you want only the most recent submitted employee, instead of passing all data (`empInfoData`) to the template, pass `empFormSave` which is the newly saved instance